# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el nombre de una variable que empieza por https a http en html o typeScript?

Tags: html, bootstrap, typescript, api, google-api

Mirar abajo del todo para seguir el problema al día, el problema está siendo que pongo el link de la imagen en el 'src' y aún así sigue sin salirme la imagen, la información la recojo de una api, aquí os muestro el html:

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div class="col-md-3 my-2" *ngFor="let oficio of oficios">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header bg-success d-flex justify-content-center text-light text-uppercase">
        {{oficio.name}}
      </div>
      <img src="{{oficio.imgUrl}}" alt="{{oficio.name}}" class="card-img-top">
      <div class="card-body">
        {{oficio.imgUrl}}
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
        {{oficio._id}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dirección URL que me suelta en el div class="card-body"': https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/ng/modules/mmorpg/encyclopedia/jobs/assets/images/2.jpg

Adjunto imagen de como se ve.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PRROBLEMA:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SOLUCION:
Una persona me ha dicho que si hago  un cambio en el siguiente enlace -- http://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/ng/modules/mmorpg/encyclopedia/jobs/assets/images/2.jpg -- cambio el https por el http, me debe funcionar ya que https es un protocolo seguro, entonces, cómo puedo cambiar eso si recojo la información de una api?

---

### Después de cambiar la manera que interpolo: <img [src]="oficio.imgUrl" alt="{{oficio.name}}" class="card-img-top">

```
<div class="bg-dark border border-2 mt-4 mb-5 p-5 bg-opacity-50" style="width: 100em">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-3 my-2" *ngFor="let clase of clases">
      <div class="card" [routerLink]="'/clase/' + clase._id">
        <div class="card-header bg-success d-flex justify-content-center text-light text-uppercase">
          {{clase.name}}
        </div>
        <img [src]="clase.maleImg" alt="{{clase.name}}" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-footer text-center">
          {{clase.ankamaId}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

IMAGEN DEL ERROR:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y qué error te da la consola?

Comment: No me da ningún error aparente, la dirección la recoge bien, solo que al ver la página en el explorador, sale un icono de imagen pequeña, pero el icono de imagen por defecto, y el nombre de la imagen (que es lo que he puesto en el apartado 'alt' del <img>). No carga la imagen como tal.

Comment: Eso significa que no ha podido cargar la imagen, revisa el apartado red de la herramienta de desarrolladores, algo debes ver en la solicitud realizada a dicha dirección.

Comment: Adjunto nueva foto con el problema.

Comment: http 403 significa que no tienes permisos para acceder a esos recursos. Entonces a) está mal hecha la ruta, o b) debes configurar permisos en algún lugar

Comment: La ruta está bien porque me sale bien como texto, lo de configurar permisos ya ni idea.

Comment: Hola Hugo, cambia la manera que interpolas: 
<img [src]="oficio.imgUrl" alt="{{oficio.name}}" class="card-img-top"> y si falla comparte el codigo html que te renderiza el navegador

Comment: @JulioDaza, vale, ahora mismo lo hago.

Comment: @JulioDaza, ya te lo he subido.